# Add autoprefixer in webpack

Tags: webpack, sass

My webpack.config.js file:

```
var path = require("path"),
    src = path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    dist = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    webpack = require("webpack");

var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
var ExtractPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin"),
    CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin"),
    CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

var extractCssPlugin = new ExtractPlugin({
  filename: "css/main.min.css"
});

var extractHtmlPlugin = new ExtractPlugin({
  filename: "[name].html"
});

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: src + "/app/app.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: dist,
    filename: 'js/[name].min.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: src,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query:{
                    presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
                }
            },
      {
          test: /\.pug$/,
          loaders: ['file-loader?name=[name].html', 'pug-html-loader?pretty&exports=false']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: extractCssPlugin.extract({
          use:[
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {sourceMap: true, minimize: true}
            },
            {
              loader: "sass-loader",
              options: {sourceMap: true}
            },
            "postcss-loader"
          ]
        })
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    cleanPlugin,
    copyPlugin,
    extractCssPlugin,
    extractHtmlPlugin,
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

My postcss.config.js inside src/css/postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [require("autoprefixer")]
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p",
    "build:dev": "webpack -d"
  },
  "browserslist": ["last 2 versions"],
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.17",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "extract-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^3.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "pug-html-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "postcss-import": "^11.1.0",
    "precss": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

Just need to add autoprefixer to my css code once the main.scss is compiled to main.css in webpack. I did try using the post-css loader, but I couldn't get it right.

Comment: What problems did you have with `postcss-loader`? It should do what you want.

Comment: The problem i it jut wouldnt do anything... maybe cause i wasnt using it the right way but i really couldnt figure it out... could u please help me out with some solution here?

Comment: I have modified my question to answer the postcss part which i am unable to get. it does nothing at all... probably coz i m not using it the right way... so really need help here... Thanks!

Comment: can you add your `package.json`? that makes it easier to reproduce with the exact versions.

Comment: Have updated my question with the package.json file...

Comment: It works fine for me. Which properties are not getting prefixed? I tried `box-shadow` and it complies fine with `-webkit-box-shadow`

Comment: none... when i inspect element, i dont see properties like transition and transform updating with autoprefxers :/

Comment: I have no problems.. I created a repo with your files. Can you check this out and see if that works? https://github.com/lukas-reineke/autoprefixer-webpack-test

Comment: Sure... I'll take a look... Thanks!

Comment: I really dont know why it isn't working :/

Comment: Is my repo working for you?

Comment: i tried, and since there isnt an index.html file, it isnt working here. Could u add index.pug and have it compiled to index.html?

Comment: coz i get this in the page "Cannot GET /"

Comment: just run `npm run build:prod` and look in the file that gets created in `dist/css/`

Comment: could u make it possible when running "npm run build:dev"? coz it's more convenient that way when running a project and looking for prefixes in css code...

Comment: could u please add an index.pug file and have it compiled to index.html in the dist folder? coz currently m using an index.pug file and i am unfortunately not getting any results...

Comment: You could have done this yourself. And the html / pug file won't effect what is bundled in css. But I updated the repo now. Take a look.

Comment: Apologies for the trouble.. :/... it still doesnt work... ill just take another look... see what step i am missing... and will let u know... Thanks!

Comment: I understood why i am not still getting. So thing is it is targeting the sass code only inside the "style.scss". it does not target the imported sass code. :/ Any solution on this?

Comment: Ah of course. I'll write an answer, give me a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the loader is important for webpack.
Currently, you first prefix everything in all the root files that get loaded form javascript with the postcss-loader.
Then resolve the imports from within the scss files with the sass-loader.
This means that all secondary imports won't get prefixed.

This is an easy fix. Just put the sass-loader first, and you will also want to add `sourceMap` to the postcss-loader.

```
use:[
  {
    loader: "css-loader",
    options: {sourceMap: true, minimize: true}
  },
  {
    loader: "postcss-loader",
    options: {sourceMap: true}
  },
  {
    loader: "sass-loader",
    options: {sourceMap: true}
  },
]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer... it worked... it was just the order... :)